# How to insert a character every nth character in a pandas dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

One column of my dataframe contains mac addresses without colons.
I would like to add a colon to every mac address after every 2nd character.

I was looking for a split every nth character option of pd.Series.split.str() so that I could split the mac address in six and concat afterwards but according to the documentation splitting on number of characters is not available. There is the regex option, but regex is not a skill I have.

I assume there is an even easier solution than splitting and concatting but I have not come across that.

Help would be much appreciated, thank you.

```
      mac_address
0     0003E6A584C2
1     0003E6A584CC
2     0003E6A584DA
3     0003E6A584DC
4     0003E6A584E4
```

Comment: I had typed semicolon where the should have colon. I have edited the mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let us try `findall` with `map` (`..` means N = 2)

```
df.mac_address.str.findall('..').map(':'.join)
Out[368]: 
0    00;03;E6;A5;84;C2
1    00;03;E6;A5;84;CC
2    00;03;E6;A5;84;DA
3    00;03;E6;A5;84;DC
4    00;03;E6;A5;84;E4
Name: mac_address, dtype: object
```

Comment: `N = 2;  df.mac_address.str.findall('.' * N).map(';'.join)` :)

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this?

```
N = 2
df['mac_address'] = df['mac_address'].str[:N] + ':' + df['mac_address'].str[N:]
```

Output:

```
>>> df
     mac_address
0  00:03E6A584C2
1  00:03E6A584CC
2  00:03E6A584DA
3  00:03E6A584DC
4  00:03E6A584E4
```

Comment: They have asked for a semicolon after every 2nd character (split into 6). So I believe they are looking for `00;03;E6;A5;84;C2`

Answer (score 1):

You're correct that regex is your friend:

```
df['mac_address'].replace(r'(\w{2})',r'\1:',regex=True).str.strip(':')
```

Output:

```
0    00:03:E6:A5:84:C2
1    00:03:E6:A5:84:CC
2    00:03:E6:A5:84:DA
3    00:03:E6:A5:84:DC
4    00:03:E6:A5:84:E4
Name: mac_address, dtype: object
```

**Note**: `r'(\w{2})'` finds all groups of two characters, then `r'\1:'` replaces each of the previous group with itself (`\1`) and a `:`. Finally, we chain that with `str.strip(':')` to remove the potential trailing `:`.

Answer (score 0):

Using `str.format` and a df `apply` function, not the nicest but it works!

```
df['mac_address'] = df['mac_address'].apply(lambda x: '{}:{}:{}:{}:{}:{}'.format(x[:2],x[2:4],x[4:6],x[6:8],x[8:10],x[10:]))

         mac_address
0  00:03:E6:A5:84:C2
1  00:03:E6:A5:84:C2
2  00:03:E6:A5:84:C2
3  00:03:E6:A5:84:C2
4  00:03:E6:A5:84:C2
5  00:03:E6:A5:84:C2
```